# Design Disappears in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

While I was working on a project tonight, I created a textview. I also created a void with the text view. When I deleted the void connect to the textview, I got an error and my layout disappears when I went back into it. When I click on the layout, the buttons are still there, but I just can't see them. I closed and reopened the project, but couldn't fix it. Please help me!!!

Comment: Would you mind to post a screenshot of what you're seeing and maybe some code examples? That would make it easier to understand the situation that you're in in order to help you out.

Comment: Which version of visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand about this situation, is you deleted an event listener's function, but you never deleted the code attempting to add said function as an event listener.
You deleted `void textControl_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)` or whatever event/item it is, but not where it is added to the text control. This causes an error, as you can't add an event listener that doesn't exist.
There should be a button that says `Go to code` on it, and it should take you to your error and you can fix it there. If this isn't your problem, this is what I understood from your question.